# How i can add images in card inside gridview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

images not loading and not even getting error

[image]

```dart
   Card( elevation: 5.0, child: Image.asset( 'Assets/images/profile.jpeg', fit: BoxFit.cover, ), ),
```

Comment: did you add the image to your pubspec? can you post the pubspec.yaml?

Comment: Yes i already added but still not showing up did images conflict with cards if the image size is big  ? ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add your image location into pubspec.yaml

```
Card(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("Assets/images/profile.jpeg"),
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```